# Pdf-tools: Toggle between viewing and editing mode

Tags: pdf-tools, docview

In DocView (without pdf-tools installed) I could hit `C-c C-c` to toggle between viewing-mode and editing-mode. After installing pdf-tools I expected `C-c C-c` to act the same. But now it toggles between PDFView and DocView, without any editing mode. What can I do to make it toggle between PDFView and editing mode?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the command you would need to invoke to edit the pdf is:

M-x pdf-virtual-edit-mode

I don't think toggling is possible but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard hooks to remap `C-c C-c` and use it as a toggle key, seems to be the easiest way:

```lisp
;; edit -> view
(add-hook 'pdf-virtual-edit-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key pdf-virtual-edit-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'pdf-view-mode)
            ))

;; view -> edit
(add-hook 'pdf-view-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key pdf-view-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") #'pdf-virtual-edit-mode)
            ))
```